# Is it best practice to always store dates in GMT and then adjust on display?

Tags: ios, nsdate

I am trying to get a better understanding of dates.  I'm noticing that IOS seems to want to do everything in standard GMT dates.  That is when you ask it for now, it gives you GMT.

This is creating complexity as when I set reminders for the future (and set them in core data), I cant just set them based on current time for user but need to convert them to GMT for storage, back to actual for display and then if the user does something to the display convert back again to GMT.

What is best practice for going back and forth between actual local date and GMT.

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSDate objects represent themselves internally in GMT, and all date-based calculations are based on GMT.

Saving a date to Core Data as a string is silly. Don't do that.

If memory serves, you can save your dates as NSDate objects directly in Core Data. Alternately, use timeIntervalSince1970 (to create a "Unix date") and save the date in Core Data as a double.

Comment: I am storing them as NSDates.  The question is whether they should always be stored in the default GMT or whether I should first convert them to actual time and store them as the real time (as a NSDate).   My preference would be real time as the app syncs with a MYSql database that uses local times but Apple does not seem to like that.

Comment: I guess what is confusing me is how much work core data does behind scenes. If you select 11:00AM one week from today in date picker and you are in Eastern Time Zone, does it simply save as 11:00AM one week away or does it convert it to GMT?  Similarly, if it is saved in core data as 6AM, does it display as 6AM or does it convert to whatever time zone device is in at the time of displaying?

Comment: It's not Core Data, it's the OS. NSDates are always stored in GMT. When you use a date picker, it uses the time zone of some locale (usually the user's locale and time zone.) How you display it depends. Usually you want to create a date formatter, which again has a locale and time zone, and which will also default to the user's locale/time zone.